# How to add a delay (offset by time) to an objects transform properties that are being driven by another object

Tags: animation-nodes

Basically I have a Cube and a Sphere. I have copied the transform of the Cube using transform input to a vector math node (set to add to add an offset) and then to the Spheres transform output. Now when I move the Cube the Sphere moves at the exact same time. I want to add a time delay to it so that when I move the Cube, the sphere moves say 10 frames later and always has this delay in moving.
I've seen people doing something similar using instancer setup, but I dont want to create instances, I just want the sphere to move with a delay relative to that of the cube.
How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Action. Here transforms from cube are transferred to sphere with a delay using `Delay Action` node.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you. I need to spend a lot more time with nodes :D